# Magento 2 Create Product Customizable Option programmatically without using objectmanager

Tags: magento2, customizable-options

Magento 2 How to create the Product Customizable options without using the Objectmanager.I saw many tutorials but the all tutorials is used the objectmanager.Magento Coading Standard does not allow the objectmanager.

Thank you so much

Comment: Please post the code which you tried or tutorial link which you are following

Comment: https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-create-customizable-options-programmatically/